# signon-ui "Enter your credentials" dialog on desktop

Tags: 14.04

I have just installed Trusty and have rebooted a couple times. However this time I have been greeted by this strange dialog when I logged in.

[image]

I have no idea what kind of credentials it asked and which app shows this dialog. I clicked the `Cancel` button but it keeps popping up.

Does anyone know what dialog is it? How to figure out which process it belongs to?

**Edit:** I figured out that this dialog came from signon-ui. So, I think it asked my Ubuntu SSO credentials. However, after I put my Ubuntu credentials into it, it keeps showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also found a fix for this. In my case, it was also a Yahoo account in Online Accounts which was the culprit.

Symptoms of a faulty Yahoo account in Online Accounts manifest as the following:
When you go to System Settings > Online Accounts, click on your Yahoo Account in left column, then click on "Edit Options", there will be NO information displayed - window will be blank instead of the expected username & password fields.

To fix a faulty Yahoo account in Online Accounts you need to delete the account and re-add it:
Go to System Settings > Online Accounts, click your Yahoo Account in left column, click "Remove Account", then click "+ Add account..."
The username & password fields will display as expected and you can fill out your account info.
Congratulations, the "Enter your credentials" popup is now gone when you reboot.

Answer (score 0):

After I read that `signon-ui` is a package related to Online Accounts, I removed all my accounts from Online Accounts. There were only two accounts, and both are Yahoo accounts. After that, those annoying dialogs dissapeared.

I stored those accounts in `Online Accounts` for Empathy. So I think I can't use Empathy.